# The Not-operation in fuzzy logic

Tags: real-analysis, fuzzy-logic

If we have a function $f(x)\,:\,[0,1]\mapsto[0,1]$, which is continuous and montonically decreasing, satisfies $f(0)=1, f(1)=0$ (to agree with classical logic) and is an involution, i.e.,

$$f(f(x))=x,\quad\forall x\in[0,1],$$

do these conditions uniquely determine that the logic "not" function must be $f(x)=1-x$? If yes, please give a proof. If no, please give an alternative $f(x)$ that also has these properties.

Background: In fuzzy logic, truth and falsehood are a matter of degree, which can be between $0$ and $1$. This question asks about whether the definition of the fuzzy "not" operation is unique in order to preserve certain properties of the classical logic.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: Up to now I have only tried many "well-behaved" functions and found that if $f(x)$ is nonlinear, so is $f(f(x))$, which then does not satisfy the involutory condition. But this is not a proof.

Comment: If you're looking for a uniquely defined not function, you'll need to specify what and and or functions you're using in your system of fuzzy logic as well as which boolean logic rules you want your system to maintain.

Comment: The "and" was $\min$ and the "or" was $\max$. Then de Morgan's laws require my $f(x)$ to be monotonically decreasing. And I just added the continuity condition to look for well-behaved alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this works on $[0, 1]$?

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$$

Comment: I see. In fact, whenever the graph of $f(x)$ is symmetric about the straight line $y=x$, it will satisfy the conditions. Thank you for your example.

Comment: Sf(f(x)) = x$ will be satisfied if the function is symmetric along $y=x$, but there are 3 other conditions that need to also be satisfied. However, the example I give does satisfy those as well.

Comment: Yeah. Because our definition of what a function is does not treat $x$ and $y$ on equal footing, the examples that we normally try (e.g. polynomials) wouldn't easily satisfy the symmetry about $y=x$.